# How to access a javascript variable written in a QML file from C++

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10

I need to access a javascript variable(written in a qml file) from c++. I am working with blackberry 10 NDK. How do I do this?

Comment: I'd say javascript variables stay within the js scope. So you can't. But you can access QML properties from C++ which behave just like javascript variables.